# Are there any "non-research" jobs in Asian HiEd available to foreigners?

Tags: asia, south-east-asia

it is me again.

If anyone has experience working in SE Asia, I would love to hear from you.
I am wondering if there are any "non-research" jobs in Asian universities and colleges. I have a Ph.D. in "life sciences", currently live and work in Canada. Unfortunately, the job market for people with such qualification is really bad in Canada (I would say, almost non-existing). In general, there are very few jobs in Canada, where pay is actually commensurate with the cost of living (which is getting higher and higher), but I digress. Sometimes, I try to contemplate some backup/exit strategies. Idea of working in Asia is one of them. To be clear, I have no other motives, except monetary. It appears to me that job market is better overseas and it might  be not as difficult to find a job in SE Asia. What I am wondering about is this: are there any jobs in Asian Higher Ed. that are between a "postdoc" and a "professor", something like a "lecturer". I do not have any energy left in me to go for a "postdoc" (it would be a torture for me) and I do not have good research record to even apply for prof. position. It would be great to know that there is something "above" the proverbial "English teacher" (I do not like children, in general).
Last, but not least: how is it financially? I understand that these type of jobs do not offer good salaries, but again, in big cities in Canada post.doc salary is extremely restrictive. But if compensation for these jobs is as bad as "adjuncting" in the USA, then it not worth it, obviously.

Comment: You could try Fulbright University and the various branch campuses of Western universities in SE Asia.

Comment: Can you delete all the superfluous stuff from your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In China, there are some lecturer positions in universities that do not require to do research. The salary is lower than that of an assistant professor (that does research) and also the teaching load is higher. For example, at some university, lecturers are required to teach over 350-400 hours a year. The salary as well as living expenses can vary quite a lot depending on the city and university. There is a great need for English teachers but other topics can be possible. For the work permit, as I remember it requires a bachelor degree and 2 years experience, and as a Canadian, you are in the list of countries considered as native speaker eligible for teaching English.  Other possibilities for teaching English is to teach in a training center for professionals rather than teaching for kids.  For English teaching jobs, there are several agents looking for teachers that you may contact or you may talk with universities directly.  By the way, I think you also need to check the requirements for entering the country. During the pandemic, some countries have stricter rules for giving work permits (e.g China). It may not be the best moment to look for a job.

Comment: To the OP, the last two sentences are very critical at least for this year. I would wait until 2022 if I were you.

Comment: Phil, thank you for this detailed answer! I appreciate it.  Definitely, right now is not a good time to travel, but I want to do my research on this topic while it is not pressing. Could you recommend some places where such agents place their ads? Thank you.

Comment: @user136555 You are welcome. I would suggest to join some Facebook groups related to foreigners in China and then to ask there (there are many such groups). I often see the posts from agents who are recruiting in various cities. I heard also there are some websites for searching for English teaching jobs.  For Universities, you may try to contact with them directly or look for advertisements.